# Problem with accent marks in a search in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice

I try to make a Koine Greek dictionary with Libreoffice Calc. I have a search form and a sheet with the data. I get most of it to work by looking at MS Excel tutorials. I use Vlookup and SEARCH. But there is one problem I can not find an answer to. The problem is that Calc sees accented letters as different as not accented (at least in Greek). But I want it to handle it the same.

For example:
If I search for **διδασκω**
it should give the result **διδάσκω - I teach**

At the moment it only works when given the correct accents.
I hope somebody here knows a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[U+03AC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03ac/index.htm) is a composed character, containing both the alpha and the accent.  So, there is no way to search for the vowel separated from the accent.

To search for either accented or unaccented, use a regular expression:

```
=SEARCH("διδ[αά]σκω", "εγω διδάσκω")
```

Another option would be to replace `U+03AC` with its decomposed sequence throughout your entire dictionary:

```
U+03B1 U+0301 = ά
```

Then both of these work:

```
=SEARCH("διδα\u0301?σκω", "εγω διδάσκω")
=SEARCH("διδα\u0301?σκω", "εγω διδασκω")
```

**EDIT**:

Set the formulas of `Search.F3:Search.F5` to the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E3, "α", "[αά]")
=SUBSTITUTE(F3, "ι", "[ιί]")
=SUBSTITUTE(F4, "ω", "[ωώ]")
```

This produces:

```
διδ[αά]σκω
δ[ιί]δ[αά]σκω
δ[ιί]δ[αά]σκ[ωώ]
```

Then for the main lookup formula:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH($Search.$F$5, $C$2:$C$1000, 1),"")
```

Comment: Ok, is it maybe possible to put it in a formula?
The code I use to search is this one: `=IFERROR(SEARCH($Search.$E$3, $C$2:$C$1000, 1),"")` Is it possible to enter some code that applies this codewide α=ά ο=ό etc. So that it will search for all possibilities (δίδασκω, διδάσκω, διδασκώ) ?

Comment: Yes; see edited answer.